# How To check if wifi option enabled or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to check if wifi option is enabled on the iPhone or not (but maybe iPhone not connected to one of the wifi net).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this you need to import reachability classes in your project.

After then:-

```
#import "Reachability.h"
```

In you view DidLoad write:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    Reachability *internetReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
    [internetReach startNotifer];
    Reachability *wifiReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] retain];
    [wifiReach startNotifer];

    NetworkStatus netStatus1 = [internetReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    NetworkStatus netStatus2 = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(netStatus1 == NotReachable && netStatus2 == NotReachable)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"This feature requires an internet connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
    }
    else
    {//wifi connection available;
}
}
```

Comment: If the internat is reachable but wi-fi option disabled...This will work?

Answer (score 4):

Found a great line of code for this.
Add the Reachability class to your project and then you can do this:

```
BOOL isConnectedProperly = ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] == ReachableViaWiFi);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  First import Reachability files into your project.

 -(void)loginButtonTouched
{  
  bool success = false;
  const char *host_name = [@"www.google.com" 
             cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

  SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName
                                                (NULL, host_name);
  SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
  success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
  bool isAvailable = success && (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) && 
                   !(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);

  if (isAvailable) 
  {
      NSLog(@"Host is reachable: %d", flags);
      // Perform Action if Wifi is reachable and Internet Connectivity is present
  }
  else
  {
      NSLog(@"Host is unreachable");
      // Perform Action if Wifi is reachable and Internet Connectivity is not present
  }       
}
```

When `loginButtonTouched` method is called we check that [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) is reachable or not.
`SCNetworkReachabilityFlags` returns flags which helps us to understand the Status of internet connectivity.
If `isAvailable` variable returns "true" then Host is
Reachable means Wifi is reachable and Internet Connectivity is present.

Comment: You can refer to link for more help on same topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705654/to-check-wifi-is-on-but-no-internet-connectivity/6705836#6705836