# Check if Wifi is Enabled (Not if connected to the internet, just if its enabled)

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi

As the title says, I just need to check if Wifi is enabled.
Ive tried reachability in apples documentation but as far as I can tell, that checks for an internet connection, but it doesn't matter whether its connected or not.
I am able to check whether bluetooth is enabled, but I just need wifi now.
thanks

Comment: How did you try reachability? Did you try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7975750/756976 - e.g. `NetworkStatus netStatus2 = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];` using `[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi]`

Comment: @skofgar thanks for your commment, but isnt it's reachability status received from checking if its "reached" a domain?

Comment: good question. I think it checks only if it has a wifi connection and not if it can access the internet. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html